# Optaplanner persistent data in session

Tags: java, database, jpa, persistence, optaplanner

Every time I create a new skill, or employee, or  contract, nothing gets saved to the database. When i re-run the application from intelliJ, then go to my browser at localhost, all the data I previously created in the previous session is not there anymore. How can I persist the new data I create in Optaplanner, so that when I re-run the application it is present on the UI?

Comment: Are you saving to the DB? ```record.save()``` or ```record.update()```. If so? Is the DB running accross your restarts of the Application? Is your DB a in memory only DB?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really saving it to the DB. Im new to optaplaner and i don't know how to check that. I just downloaded the code the open source optaplaner, and have't done any changes to it.

Comment: Are you using optaweb-employee-rostering? Or one of the optaplanner-quickstarts? Or nurse rostering of optaplanner-examples?

Comment: yes, I'm using optaweb-employee-rostering

Answer (score 0):

I am using `solveAndListen` on `solverManager` and this calls `save()` when it has an improved score. You need to persist the solution / result in here. I am using Hibernate to do it. I just update the latest solution in database rather than storing a new version of it but that is up to you. Just be prepared that there can be a lot of calls to save early in the execution. I have created an additional API to reset the solver so I can rerun it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I just want to create a new skill on the browser, save it, then stop the application. When I re-run the application, go the browser, I would like to see the skill I created in the previous session. 
At this time, the skill I created in the previous session is not present in the new session.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that this is about optaweb-employee-rostering:

The development [application.properties](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/master/optaweb-employee-rostering-backend/src/main/resources/application.properties) are using **an in memory database that is deleted after every run**.

But [the production application properties](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/master/optaweb-employee-rostering-backend/src/main/resources/application-production.properties) use PostgreSQL (and you can switch that to your preferred database).

The OpenShift (=Kubernetes) support sets up both optaweb-employee-rostering and PostgreSQL pods IIRC. To use that, run `runOnOpenshift.sh` which is [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering).

Comment: thanks. yes it is about optaweb-employee-rostering. 
I tried the command runOnOpenshift.sh, but i get this answer: 
sh runOnOpenshift.sh

readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
ERROR: The oc client tool needs to be installed to connect to OpenShift.

Comment: While the ./runOnOpenshift.sh is running, The script successfully run the command `oc new-build --name backend --strategy=docker --binary`, but it terminates at this command `oc start-build backend --from-dir=${dir_backend} --follow` 
This is the error message i get now.

```Uploading directory "optaweb-employee-rostering-backend" as binary input for the build 
...............................................................
Uploading finished
Error from server (BadRequest): unable to wait for build backend-1 to run: timed out waiting for the condition```